# Why is XOR called a controlled inverter?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I wonder why XOR is called a controlled inverter?

Comment: ... Because one input controls if the other is inverted...

Comment: The decision which one is the control input is very tough.

Comment: https://youtu.be/8IodGjURPsY?t=7m

Comment: "To be or Not to be ", 1+1=0

Comment: @Gregory Kornblum: that got a giggle.

Answer (score 5):

An XOR gate has the following truth table.

```
 A  B | Q
------+---
 0  0 | 0
 0  1 | 1
------+---
 1  0 | 1
 1  1 | 0
```

I've split it up into two parts.

Can you see now where the name comes from?

You can consider that `A` is the control pin, and `B`/`Q` are the data bus being controlled.